# Having issue creating a coupon machine

Tags: java

I have a mini task and am just stuck to find out for a solution. In a nutshell;

let's say you coded a "Video Game Coupons Machine" or something else which works like, when you input your coupon number, then this machine should solve how much gumballs and candies I may have. You should redeem 10 coupons to have 1 candy and 3 coupons to have 1 gumball.

So this being said "1 candy = 10 coupon" and "1 gumball = 3 coupon".

Example;
You scan the code number as "13" and it should say you can have 1 candy and 1 coupon number. I think candies=couponNumbers/10. Am I right? However, how to find how much gumball I might have automatically?

I've written the code I've tried below;

```
int candies, gumballs, numOfCoupons;    

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number of coupons:");
numOfCoupons=scan.nextInt();

candies=couponNumbers/10;
gumballs=candies%3; //This is where I do have a problem or I think so.. don't know exactly.

System.out.println("Number of Candies: " + candies);
System.out.println("Number of Gumballs: " + gumballs);
```

Another example; you scan the number as 64, then you should be able to have 6 candies and still 1 gumball but when you put a number less than 10 and equal or greater than 3, you should still have some gumballs only, not candy as it should be appear like "0". Etc etc..

Thanks for your reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more examples:
(numberOfCoupns -> candies, gumballs)

```
   1 ->   0, 0
   2 ->   0, 0
   5 ->   0, 1
   6 ->   0, 2
   9 ->   0, 3 

 391 ->  39, 0
 392 ->  39, 0
 395 ->  39, 1
 396 ->  39, 2
 399 ->  39, 3

1941 -> 194, 0
1942 -> 194, 0
1945 -> 194, 1
1946 -> 194, 2
1949 -> 194, 3
```

So maybe you've seen a pattern:

```
candies = numOfCoupons / 10;
```

appears to be correct. If you take a closer look at the gumballs, you'll see that it can be seen as totally independent of the number of candies. Notice that the number of gumballs is equal for each example group. The last digits of the number of coupons in the example groups are also the same. This correlation should be reflected in your code. The gumball count can be derived from the last digit of the number of coupons.

To get the last digit of the number of coupons, you can do `numberOfCoupons % 10`. Then you can divide that last digit by 3 and get your gumball count:

```
gumballs = (numOfCoupons % 10) / 3;
```